# Puppet-agent not found after dpkg .deb on embedded device

Tags: ubuntu, embedded, puppet

I have the following script which installs Puppet 4 agent.

```
PUPPET_AGENT_VERSION="1.8.3"
UBUNTU_CODENAME="trusty"

apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y wget ca-certificates lsb-release && \
    wget https://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-pc1-"$UBUNTU_CODENAME".deb && \
    dpkg -i puppetlabs-release-pc1-"$UBUNTU_CODENAME".deb && \
    rm puppetlabs-release-pc1-"$UBUNTU_CODENAME".deb && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y puppet-agent="$PUPPET_AGENT_VERSION"-1"$UBUNTU_CODENAME" && \
    apt-get remove --purge -y wget && \
    apt-get autoremove -y && \
    apt-get clean && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

When I run this code inside a docker container I have which is running Ubuntu 14 *trusty* it works fine.

I then try to run the same script on an embedded controller also running Ubuntu 14 trusty and I get back:

> E: Version '1.8.3-1trusty' for 'puppet-agent' was not found

The script does successfully download the `.deb` file and runs `dpkg -i` yet the package can't be found. I also try manually running through the script and installing without version `apt-get install puppet-agent` and I get a similar error.

I'm wondering why nothing is showing up even after running `dpkg -i` when the same code seems to work on the virtual controller? Could it have something to do with the difference in system architecture between my docker container and the actual embedded device?

---

***Running `uname -a` on each.***

Docker Container: `Linux myorg-HP-EliteBook-8560p 4.8.0-52-generic #55~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 28 14:36:29 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Device: `Linux ws1-mtl-philip 3.0.36+ #10 SMP PREEMPT Wed Mar 22 14:24:56 EDT 2017 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux`

---

I'm still interested in knowing more about the possible differences in apt repos between architectures.

As a work around I ended up installing puppet via `gem install puppet`.

There are also tar files available from puppet [here](https://downloads.puppetlabs.com/puppet/).

Comment: The embedded system has a different architecture. There may not be a Puppet AIO for that arch on Trusty. If there is, you may need to specify arch for apt. Update: I just checked and there is in fact no AIO Puppet package for any OS with arm.